# Token cannot be null on the instantiation of the Product Query Builder. / Query Akeneo 2

Tags: symfony3.x, akeneo, pim

I would like to create a command akeneo into my bundle who query my products like [this](https://docs.akeneo.com/2.3/manipulate_pim_data/product/query.html).

*So, after multiple test, i have always this error:*

> In ProductQueryBuilderFactory.php line 68:
>   Token cannot be null on the instantiation of the Product Query
>   Builder.

*Here is my code :*

```
$pqbFactory =  $this->getApplication()->getKernel()->getContainer()->get('pim_catalog.query.product_query_builder_factory');
$pqb = $pqbFactory->create(['default_locale' => 'fr_FR', 'default_scope' => 'ecommerce']);  // error
```

Comment: Don't forget to give your Akeneo PIM version, response you receive may vary a lot depending on the version you use :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complete Julien's answer, note that **this error comes only if you are using the Enterprise Edition** (EE). Indeed, in the EE, we decorate the normal `product_query_builder_factory` to apply permission.

If you don't want to apply permission (*and don't use any token*), you can use the `pim_catalog.query.product_query_builder_factory_without_permission`:

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->boot();

$pqbFactory =  $kernel->getContainer()->get('pim_catalog.query.product_query_builder_factory_without_permission');
$pqb = $pqbFactory->create(['default_locale' => 'fr_FR', 'default_scope' => 'ecommerce']);  // you won't have any error
```

Answer (score 2):

The PQB needs to have an authenticated user to be able to apply right filters on the results. To authenticate a user in your command you can take inspiration from the [get product command](https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/blob/master/src/Pim/Bundle/CatalogBundle/Command/GetProductCommand.php#L102). We simply take a `--username` argument and manually add it to the token storage.

```
$userManager = $this->getContainer()->get('pim_user.manager');
$user = $userManager->findUserByUsername($username);

if (null === $user) {
    $output->writeln(sprintf('<error>Username "%s" is unknown<error>', $username));

   return false;
}

$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());
$this->getTokenStorage()->setToken($token);
```